# Roots of linear combination of $x \sin x$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, rootfinding

Let $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2,\cdots \theta_n)$, and $a_{ij}$ are constants. There is no condition on the positiveness of $a_{ij}$.

Under which condition on $\theta$, such that the following function only has one type of root, which is all $\theta_i$ equals, i.e. $\theta_i-\theta_j=0$, for any $(i,j)$ pair?

\begin{equation}\label{1}
\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n} a_{ij} (\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)=0,\text{ for }t\in(0,1].
\end{equation}

**What I already know is the case $a_{ij}\geq 0$**

If $a_{ij}$ is element in the adjacency matrix of a connected graph (thus, $a_{ij}\geq 0$), then by imposing the constriant $\theta_i-\theta_j\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, we have
$$(\theta_i-\theta_j)t\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)\geq\frac{2}{\pi}(t^2(\theta_i-\theta_j)^2),\text{ for }t\in(0,1]$$
since $x\sin x\geq \frac{2}{\pi}x^2$ for $x\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ (see the figure of $x\sin x$ below)

Thus
$$\frac{1}{t}a_{ij} (\theta_i-\theta_j)t\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)\geq a_{ij}\frac{2}{\pi}t(\theta_i-\theta_j)^2,\text{ for }t\in(0,1]$$ which allows us to conclude that $\theta_i-\theta_j=0$.

**My question specifically regarding the case that $a_{ij}$ can be both positive, zero and negative**.

Any idea would be much appreciated!

**Update:**
Since writing in comments about the following is too long, I write here as answer. Thanks for @Alexandre Eremenko pushing forward. I still have no idea how to proceed the case (2) and (3), which means Sines are not linearly independent.

(1) If there is no $\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)$ equals, then all $\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)$ are linearly independent.

Under this condition,
since $\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)$ are linearly independent, then only when $a_{ij}(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0$ (equivalently $(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0$ since we consider $a_{ij}\neq 0$) it holds that $\sum a_{ij}(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)=0$.

(2) If there is $\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)$ equals, equivalently, there exists pair of $\theta_i-\theta_j$ equals and there exists $i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2$ such that $(\theta_i-\theta_j)+(\theta_i-\theta_j)=\pi+2k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then Sines are not linearly independent. We split into two cases:

(2.1) If there exists pair of $\theta_i-\theta_j$ equals, then for those $i^*,j^*$ that $\theta_{i^*}-\theta_{j^*}\neq 0$, we do not have further information and this needs further analysis.

(2.2) If there exists $i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2$ such that $(\theta_i-\theta_j)+(\theta_i-\theta_j)=\pi+2k\pi$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then we do not have further information and this needs further analysis.

[image]

Comment: The main identity that you wrote, before the words "What I already know", is a linear combination of sines (not functions of the form $t\sin(ct)$ as the rest of this post suggests. Is this a misprint?

Comment: In any case, this problem is easily solved by noticing that functions  $t^n\sin(kt)$ with any distinct pairs $(n,k)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko It's not a misprint, I rewrote $(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)$ as $\frac{1}{t}(\theta_i-\theta_j)t\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)$

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Hi Alexandre, Could you elaborate your idea more? Thank you very much!

Comment: I understand that $t\sin(kt)$ with different $k$ are linearly independent, which means $a_1t\sin(k_1t)+a_2t\sin(k_2t)+\cdots+a_mt\sin(k_mt)=0$ only has one solution which is $(a_1,\cdots,a_m)=(0,\cdots,0)$. However here I am solving the equation for $k_1,\cdots,k_m$ instead of $(a_1,\cdots,a_m)$.

Comment: I streamlined the text to be more readable before I realized that there were answers....anyone is welcome to revert.

Comment: @MattF. no worries, I re-edited it back.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you wrote is
$$\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}(\theta_i-\theta_j)\sin((\theta_i-\theta_j)t)=0$$
for $t\in(0,1).$. Since sines are linearly independent,
this is only possible either when $a_{i,j}(\theta_i-\theta_j)=0$ for all $i,j$ or if
$$\theta_{i_1}-\theta_{j_1}=\theta_{i_2}-\theta_{j_2}$$
for some $i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2$. Conversely, if this holds for these indices,
set $a_{i_1,j_1}=-a_{i_2,j_2}$ and the rest of $a_{i,j}=0$
and you have your identity.